# Problems concerning pointers and malloc in C90

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am quite a newbie when it comes to C, and seem to be having a few issues when it comes to memory allocation and pointers. For my assignment, we have to create the ADT of dynamic sets using arrays, and to do this we require heavy use of pointers which I find a bit difficult to grasp.

I created a structure to act as the sets

```
struct Set{

    int arrelement; //the 'size' of the array
    int * arrvalue;; //the array
}

typedef struct Set *SetArray;
```

The issue arises when I come to applying functions such as Add(where I add a unique element to the set) or Cardinality (where the programs shows me the total number of elements in the set). Adding seems to crash my program after more than 2 additions and trying to retrieve the stored data supplies junk variables.

Here is the code for the relevant functions

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "Array.h"

    int size = 1; // similar to arrelement, to be used for realloc

    SetArray Create(){ // to allocate memory for the set

        SetArray sptr;
        sptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Set));
        sptr->arrvalue = malloc(sizeof(struct Set));
        sptr->arrelement = 1;
        return sptr;
    }

    SetArray Add(SetArray sptr, int x){

        if(Is_Element_Of(x, sptr)){ //function to keep elements in set unique.
                                         //Function works, which brings me to 
                                         //believe values are being stored
            puts("Value already exists, enter a unique value");
        }
        else{
            if(sptr == NULL){
                puts("Memory Allocation Failed. Shutting down.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

            sptr = realloc(sptr, size*sizeof(struct Set)); //reallocate memory
                                                             //for the 
                                                             //new element
            sptr->arrvalue[sptr->arrelement] = x;
            sptr->arrelement++;
            size++;

        return sptr;
        }



    SetArray Remove(SetArray sptr, int x){

        if(sptr == NULL){
            puts("Memory Allocation Failed. Shutting down.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if(!Is_Element_Of(x, sptr)){
            puts("Value is not in set");
        }
        else if(sptr->arrvalue == NULL){
            puts("Set is empty. Cannot remove that which does not exist");
        }
        else{
            sptr = realloc(sptr, size*sizeof(struct Set));
            sptr->arrvalue[sptr->arrelement] = '\0';
            sptr->arrelement--;
            size--;
        }


return sptr;
}

SetArray Clear(SetArray sptr){

    if(sptr == NULL){
            puts("Memory Allocation Failed. Shutting down.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sptr->arrelement; i++){
        sptr->arrvalue[i] = '\0';
    }
    return sptr;
}
```

Also, not sure if relevant, but just in case, here is the Function Is_Element_Of

```
int Is_Element_Of(int x, SetArray sptr){

    if(sptr == NULL){
            puts("Memory Allocation Failed. Shutting down.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int flag = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sptr->arrelement; i++){
        if(sptr->arrvalue[i] == x){
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Pardon me for any mistakes, but this is my first time asking and I tried my best to keep everything organized and structured properly.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: To comment a statment you need `//` instead of `\\\``

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I hurriedly added those comments to explain to anyone reading what the purpose of said line was and forgot the proper syntax.

Comment: In that case you can edit back and improve your question again....

Answer (score 3):

You are reallocating the wrong pointer you realloc the pointer to your parent Set when you want to realloc the array it contains.

```
sptr = realloc(sptr, size*sizeof(struct Set));
```

should be

```
sptr->arrvalue = realloc(sptr->arrvalue, (sptr->arrelement+1)*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Aha, this seemed to fix my issue! Thank you very much Nathan.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your main problem is this :

```
sptr->arrvalue = malloc(sizeof(struct Set));
```

since arravlue is int*, try this :

```
sptr->arrvalue = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

edit: same for realloc

Comment: You are right that this code is incorrect, but its not going to be the cause of the issue since sizeof(struct Set) > sizeof(int))

Comment: It is the beginning of the problem, everything started there, and continued in realloc of course.